# What is the alternative to using domains and ranges within ontologies?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm playing with Protégé 5 to build ontologies. After googling around on the topic of domains and ranges, I'm seeing that domains and ranges are not necessarily the right way to relate two things.

[[protege-owl] Specifying domain and range in object properties](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/protege-owl/2010-November/015509.html):

> The important thing to remember is that OWL restrictions enable
> inference.  So what that means is that if you supply domain and range
> information for object properties, then those classes can be inferred
> based on the use of the property.  In particular, domain and ranges
> are NOT type checks in the sense of traditional programming
> languages.  They can only (sometimes) act that way if you have enough
> disjointness information to be able to create a logical inconsistency.
>
> So, for example, let's assume that we have the following ontology
>
> Class: Person
> Class: Vehicle
> Class: Engine
> Property: hasEngine :domain Vehicle :range Engine
>
> John isa Person
> John hasEngine engine-1
>
> At this point, inference will occur and conclude that John isa
> Vehicle.  This is not a type violation because the domain and range
> information are used for inference.  (If Person and Vehicle were
> declared to be disjoint classes, then an inconsistent ontology would
> result, which is closer to a classical type-checking result, but it
> only applies if the classes really are disjoint).

So, if domains and ranges are bad, then what should I use instead to model relationships between classes of Things?

**Edit:** I originally had stated that there were no domain / range fields in the new version. Almost immediately after posting this, I realized that those fields were, in fact, still available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still declare the domains and ranges of object properties in Protege 5. Here's a screenshot from the Protege 5 beta with an object property **hasParent** 
which has a domain **Human**:

[image: object property with domain in Protege 5 Beta]

You can do the same in Web Protege too:

[image: object property with domain in Web Protege]

That said, if for some reason you couldn't use **rdfs:domain** and **rdfs:range** axioms, you *can* get the same effect using restrictions and subclass axioms.  The axioms:

> p rdfs:range R
>   p rdfs:domain D

are equivalent to

> ⊤ ⊑ ∀p.R
>   ⊤ ⊑ ∀p<sup>-1</sup>.D

or in Manchester syntax

> owl:Thing **subClassOf** p **only** R
>   owl:Thing **subClassOf** (**inverse** p) **only** D

I think that the message on the list is just pointing out one of the common pitfalls that users have when coming to OWL from a typed programming language; they expect that "car72 hasSocialSecurityNumber xxx" will be an inconsistency because the domain of hasSocialNumber is Person and car72 has type Car . Instead, car72 will be inferred to have types Car and Person, which isn't inconsistent unless there are additional axioms that make it inconsistent.