# Equivalence between two domain expressions in OWL 2

Tags: logic, owl, description-logic

The text, Foundations of Semantic Web Technologies by Pascal Hitzler, Markus Krtzsch, and Sebastian Rudolph says on page 162.

[image]

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21858504/1337854) says,

> You can write *p has range D* as
>
> > ⊤ ⊑ ∀p.D
>
> which says that ⊤ (or `owl:Thing`, i.e., everything) is such that
> every one of its values for *p* must be a *D*.  By using inverse
> properties, you can get domain axioms as well.  *p has domain C* is
> equivalent to
>
> > ⊤ ⊑ ∀p<sup>-1</sup>.C

As we can see, the two expressions for range from the book and the answer match. I can not find how the expressions for domain are equivalent.

In the expression from the mentioned answer,

⊤ ⊑ ∀p<sup>-1</sup>.C

if we apply ∀p to both the sides, we get,

∀p.⊤ ⊑ C

The above differs from the one given in the book.

What is it I could be missing here?

Comment: Henriette Harmse has a post explaining the issues introduced by universal restrictions and equivalences. You don't have a stated equivalence here but top on the left side of an inclusion has the same effect. https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/05/10/understanding-owl-universal-property-restrictions/

Comment: What do you think "apply ∀p to both the sides" means? Regardless, ⊤ ⊑ ∀p-1.C does not imply ∀p.⊤ ⊑ C. In fact, it precisely implies (and is in fact equivalent to) ∃p.⊤ ⊑ C, so both _Foundations of Semantic Web Technologies_ and [the stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843521/owl-dl-property-restrictions-and-or-domain-range/21858504#21858504) are correct.

Answer (score 2):

In Description Logics, as well as in most logic (if not all), it is possible to express the same thing in different ways. In particular, DL general concept inclusion axioms *X* ⊑ *Y* can be equivalently expressed in different ways, such as *X* ⊓ ¬*Y* ⊑ ⊥ or ⊤ ⊑ ¬*X* ⊔ *Y*. If *X* or *Y* use ∀ or ∃, then it is usually possible to convert the axiom to an equivalent one that use the other quantifier. One such example is:

> ∃p.⊤ ⊑ C

which is equivalent to:

> ⊤ ⊑ ∀p<sup>−</sup>.C

My understanding of your confusion is the following: you correctly remarked that if *X* ⊑ *Y* holds then ∀*r*.*X* ⊑ ∀*r*.*Y* holds too for any *r* and any (atomic or complex) concepts *X* and *Y*. So you start from ⊤ ⊑ ∀p<sup>-1</sup>.C to derive ∀p.⊤ ⊑ ∀p.∀p<sup>-1</sup>.C, which is a correct entailment. But you seem to assume that ∀p.∀p<sup>-1</sup>.C is somehow equivalent to C, from which you conclude that ∀p.⊤ ⊑ C. This is not correct.

(As a side note, the classic notation for the inverse property of *p* is *p*<sup>−</sup>).

You must understand that if an element *e* of the universe does not have a relationship *r* with anything, then it is a member of the class ∀*r*.*X* (for instance, ∀hasChild.Human includes all those who do not have any children, so it includes at least every human beings). So, the class ∀p.∀p<sup>−</sup>.C contains all things that do not have a relation p with anything, which have no reason to be in C. QED.

I should add a proof that ∃p.⊤ ⊑ C is equivalent to ⊤ ⊑ ∀p<sup>−</sup>.C but I will leave this as an exercise to the reader ;-)